# flutter error: com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction

Tags: flutter, dart

i am getting error, but i cant figure out what is wrong.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > Android resource linking failed
     /Users/technology/Documents/UneleapLaunch/build/app/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:66: error: unexpected element <receiver> found in <manifest><application><activity>.
     /Users/technology/Documents/UneleapLaunch/build/app/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:73: error: unexpected element <receiver> found in <manifest><application><activity>.
```

[image: errorInImage]

this is my manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.iiii.iiiii">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
   <application
        android:label="iiiii"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" />
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: From the error it looks like there is something wrong with the manifest xml.

Comment: let me update the question with the xml @epatel

Comment: @epatel i have updated it with xlm

Comment: Have you placed the "receiver"s at the wrong place? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39149501/declaring-a-receiver-in-the-manifest-file-of-an-android-studio-project

Comment: @epatel i have placed the "reciever" in different position but still have some errors. but if i remove it i see a sign building